# Mdx Query Not Returning Desired Output For Top 10 Accounts

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

My requirement is that the amount values for each AccountName should be different. However, the results of the above query against my SSAS DB and Cube show that the amount values for each AccountName are the same. I have double-checked the relationships in my facts and dimensions, and they are correct.

I have also attached the snap of results of a TSQL query against the same data that I used to create the cube. The results of this query are entirely different and values for each AccountName is different.

```
WITH 
      SET [AccountAmt] AS 
        Order
        (
          NonEmpty
          (
         [Account Info].[Account Name].[Account Name].Members 
           ,[Measures].[Amount]
          )
         ,[Measures].[Amount]
         ,bdesc
        ) 
    SELECT 
      [Measures].[Amount] ON 0
     ,Head
      (
        [AccountAmt]
       ,10
      ) ON 1
    FROM  [Shell_Monthly_Cube]
    CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

[Olap Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ5A8.jpg)
[Tsql Result Against Same Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAG2x.jpg)